# Java generic type bounded to classes with specific annotation

Tags: java, generics, annotations

In java it is possible to bound the generic parameter to classes implementing specific interface, so following is possible

```
interface MyInterface {}

class MyClassA implements MyInterface {}

class MyBoundedClassA<T extends MyInterface>
```

Now what if instead the interface I would like to bound the  parameter to class annotated with specific annotation, like:

```
interface @MyAnnotation {}

@MyAnnotation
class MyClassB {}

class MyBoundedClassB<T extends MyAnnotation> // NOT possible
```

Is it possible to achieve such a behavoiur in Java?

---- EDIT

On request adding real world example. Slighly modifying the domain to make the example more understandable.

There is well known jackson library for serializing objects. This library does not support serialization of map keys other than Strings, so following is not possible out of the box

```
class TimeRange {
  LocalDateTime startDate;
  LocalDateTime endDate;

}

class SportsmenActivities {
  private Map<String, <TimeRange, List<Activity>>  sportActivities;
}
```

In this example the key of outer map is "sportsmanCode" liek "andy", "mike", "john" .Inner Map contains activities performed by given sportsman within given period.

So let's say Andy, was jogging for one day than the entry would be:

```
new SportsmanActivities().get("andy").put(TimeRange.of('2012-12-01,'2012-12-02'), List.with(new JoggingActivity)) // did some pseudo code here for readablity
```

Now as said Jackson will not serialize that out of the box, so I wrote generic module which allows serialization of such complex map.

To use that what you need to do is to annotate your "key" class like that:

```
@KeySerializable
class TimeRange {
  @MyMapKey
  LocalDateTime startDate;
  @MyMapKey
  LocalDateTime endDate;

}
```

As you can guess fields annotated with @MyMapKey will be used to generate MapKey.

Now I have a implementation of jackson class which dynamically serializes everything passed as a "text map key" annotated with @KeySerializable. The signature is follwing

```
    class MyMapKeySerializer<T> extends JsonSerializer<T> {
      serialize (T keyToSerialize) { 
      // do magic 
      }

   }
```

This works, but I would like to limit T to only accept classes annotated with @KeySerializable, as only for such classes this method makes sense. Ideally this would be something like:

```
   class MyMapKeySerializer<T annotatedWith @KeySerializable> extends JsonSerializer<T> {
      serialize (T keyToSerialize) { 
      // do magic 
      }

   }
```

Comment: Annotations are 'meta-data' which can be queried from annotated ellements. They are not considered classes/objects meaning they won't work with generics. So why do you need this mechanic? As I am sure there is an alternative solution to your problem.

Comment: @n247s: I don't think you are right. Annotations are classes which conforms to contract Class<? extends Annotation> and each annotation is represented by such a class. I need this mechanic to limit the number of classes which can be passed as a param. I want to have guarantee that classes passed as T are annotated with specific annotation (passing any other class as T does not makes sense in context of MyBoundedClassB )

Comment: @walkeros annotations themselves are instances of classes, but "this class/method/variable has that annotation" is not part of the type system.

Comment: @AndyTurner: right, but still following `MyBoundedClassB<T annotatedWith MyAnnotation>` could be possible, as annotations of class are available on compile time and compiler could inspect whether MyClassB is annotated with MyAnnotation. It could be similar to inspecting for interfaces: MyBoundedClassB<T annotatedWith MyAnnotation> and my question is how to achieve such behavior

Comment: @walkeros could be possible, but isn't.

Comment: This would be a form of structural typing, which Java does not do.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline - Why would it be "form of structural typing?" I would say it "would be" if there was no Annotation. Since the annotation is there and can be inspected by compiler (the same way as interface) it is not structural. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: @walkeros How is that different from a method being there and inspected by the compiler (the same way)?

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline: Ok.. got your point. Thanks

Comment: A tool like the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/) plugs into a compiler to restrict generic instantiation in a way similar to what you requested.  [For example](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#generics-instantiation), `class MyList<T extends @NonNull Object> {...}`.  I can't tell if this satisfies your use case.  Can you make your example more realistic and explain why you need the functionality, so we can see whether other solutions might work?

Comment: @mernst: I added example. Will look at Checker Framework, but looks interesing at the first glance and I think example given by you would satify the use case. Feel free to post that as an Answer to the question asked

Comment: @mernst: Went through example in Checker Framework's and actually doing something like `class  MyMapKeySerializer<T extends @KeySerializable Object> myList` might solve my use case. Now I would expext the compiler to fail when doing `myList.add(new String())` <- as String is not annotated with @KeySerializable. Would that work? If so this is what I'm looking for.

Comment: @walkeros Yes, I expect that would work.  I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tool like the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org) plugs into a compiler to restrict generic instantiation in a way similar to what you requested.  It is implemented as an annotation processor, and it gives a compile-time guarantee of correct use.

[For example](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#generics-instantiation), you can write `class MyList<T extends @NonNull Object> {...}`.

The Checker Framework enables you to [build your own checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#creating-a-checker), which enforces any rules you like about `@KeySerializable`.  In your case, the rules might be so simple that you can just define a couple of type qualifiers and use the [Subtyping Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#subtyping-checker) -- at least at first.

Note that for the Checker Framework to work using the `@KeySerializable` annotation, that annotation must be a type annotation rather than a declaration annotation.

Comment: Impressed about the capabilities of Checker Framework. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If your goal is to assert only annotated classes are accepted then you have few workaround options:

1. Write an annotation-processor that does the assertion at compile time (see how @NonNull etc work). This is is interesting work but non-trivial as the compilation/type system is totally new to many seasoned Java devs.
2. Use some form AOP (AspectJ, Spring AOP etc) to "advise" all annotated methods with a Decorator whose responsibility is to assert the parameter has the same annotation.
3. Explicitly check at runtime using `parameter.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)`

Comment: (+1) - 3 - parameter.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class) is actually what I'm doing, it works, but it's on runtime. 2 - is not possible, as I have annotation on class level, not on method leve, 1 - this seems iteresting. I would explore that, but I was wondering if there is similar mechnism built-in java already.

Comment: You'd be surprised how complex AspectJ pointcuts can be. I'm sure it could be done. Introducing AspectJ to a build is a significant change to a project though. https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/language-joinPoints.html