# Spring AOP with type parameter with annotation Collection<@SomeAnnotation>

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop, aspect

I want to advice methods which arguments are annotated. The exact designator I am trying is `args(Collection<@SomeAnnotation *>)` but it says "error wildcard type pattern not allowed, must use type name".

The poincut looks like this :

```java
execution(public * someMethod(..)) && args(java.util.Collection<@SomeAnnotation *>)
```

Example signatures :

- `@SomeAnnotation *` - any type marked with `@SomeAnnotation` annotation
- `Collection<@SomeAnnotation *>` - collection type, with a type parameter marked with `@SomeAnnotation` annotation

Could someone help if this is possible at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Collection<@SomeAnnotation *>` is not a valid Java expression for generics. In AspectJ, you need to stick to Java syntax for generic types. You cannot describe generic type parameters in the same way as you can describe regular types. The only syntax extension I know of and found in the documentation is the `+` syntax designating subtypes, e.g. `List<? extends Object+>`.

You want to read chapter ["Generics in AspectJ 5"](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/generics-inAspectJ5.html) from the AspectJ documentation and probably the whole [generics section](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/adk15notebook/generics.html).

[This Java question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58669916/1082681) also is related. Some workarounds and tools are discussed there.

Comment: Thanks, probably this will work in full aspectj support, but I am trying in Spring AOP. Have to make a test first. I made a quick test as well with unbound wildcard since it is valid java generic expression like `Collection<@SomeAnnotation ?>` but now it says **error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut**.

Comment: My answer was for AspectJ. But Spring also uses AspectJ functionality for pointcut matching. Simply speaking, Spring AOP's capabilities are a subset of AspectJ's. So if it is not working in AspectJ, then you don't need to hope for Spring AOP either. Your new error message is about something else. Please post a full, reproducible example. I cannot debug prose or little code snippets. Garbage in, garbage out - i.e. this way you are not going to get a good answer.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to exclude some method executions which parameters are annotated with specific annotation. What I am not able to solve is for Collection of entities. My full reproducible example is for methods executions which does not have collection of entities annotated like so :  
    @Pointcut("args(java.util.Collection<@MyAnnotation ?>)")
    void inAnnotatedEntities() {}
    
    @After("exection(* *(..) && !inAnnotatedEntities()")

Comment: You wrote a comment. That is not a fully reproducible example. Please learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is. Thank you. And again, in your code you use `<@SomeAnnotation *>` which is invalid in both Java and AspectJ. The `*` is not an allowed wildcard character for generics, only `?` is. Annotations inside generic type descriptors are illegal, too. So please don't just describe **how** you think the problem should be solved technically, but show example code explaining **what** kind of problem you are trying to solve. Others can suggest the **how** to you then.